# Filtering doesn't work with local listgrid

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I've the following problem. I add some data objecct (here Language) to a list and then to a listgrid and datasource. I want that as local data.
I can sort and group without any problems, but filter is not doing anything.

Here is my code. I've no clue and there are so many options for DataSource and ListGrid, that it seems just combinatoric guessing.

```
    List<Language> languageCodes= new ArrayList<Language>();

    final ListGrid countryGrid = new ListGrid(); 
    countryGrid.setWidth(500);  
    countryGrid.setHeight(300);  
    countryGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true);  
    countryGrid.setFilterOnKeypress(true);  
    languageCodes.add(new Language("Russian","ru", "[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ-]", true));
    languageCodes.add(new Language("Italian", "it","[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ-]",  false));
    languageCodes.add(new Language("English", "en", "[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ-]", true));
    languageCodes.add(new Language("German", "de", "[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ-]", false));
    languageCodes.add(new Language("French", "fr", "[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ-]", true));
    languageCodes.add(new Language("Greek", "el", "[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ȳЀ-ӹ-]", true));

    RecordList records= new RecordList();

    for(int i=0; i< languageCodes.size(); i++) {
        records.add(languageToRecord(languageCodes.get(i)));
    }

    DataSource ds= new DataSource();
    ds.setTestData(records.toArray());

    ds.setClientOnly(true);


    countryGrid.setDataSource(ds);

    countryGrid.setData(records);
    countryGrid.setDataFetchMode(FetchMode.LOCAL);
    countryGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    countryGrid.setAutoFetchTextMatchStyle(TextMatchStyle.SUBSTRING);


    ListGridField codeField= new ListGridField("code","Language Code", 50);
    codeField.setCanFilter(true);
    codeField.setCanEdit(true);

    ListGridField nameField= new ListGridField("name","Language Name", 60);
    nameField.setCanFilter(true);
    nameField.setCanEdit(true);
```

Any help very very welcome :)

Comment: Can you show code for `languageToRecord()` method?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code provided by OP is not sufficient to reproduce or to understand the problem.